# Tag collision between Flux (machine learning framework in Julia) and Flux (Facebook). Suggestion for a new tag name?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Search for [flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux)+[julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia) [here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux+julia).

According to the [flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux) tag, **Flux** is...

- *"An application design paradigm used as a replacement for MVC, pioneered at Facebook by Jing Chen"*.

The **Flux** referred in the Julia questions though...

- *"is an elegant approach to machine learning. It's a 100% pure-Julia stack, and provides lightweight abstractions on top of Julia's native GPU and AD support. Flux makes the easy things easy while remaining fully hackable"* (see [their repository](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl)).

How can we avoid it? Perhaps a new tag? I have a few suggestions:

- [flux-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux-machine-learning) (straightforward, it's a machine learning library after all)
- [fluxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluxml) (shortened version of the previous one, and it's also in the name of their site, fluxml.ai)
- [fluxjl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluxjl) (Flux.jl is the internal name of the library)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[flux-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux-machine-learning) was created and applied to all problematic questions I could find. I also added a simple excerpt explaining what is it about, so we can finish this already.

Let's hope this solves it already.

Answer (score 0):

Though, when you want to tag a Julia Flux question (by writing Flux in the tag field) it only recommends Facebook Flux tags. Is it possible to somehow assist by renaming (Facebook) Flux aswell and then use Flux as some sort of decision help?

Aka
Flux: see/use flux-facebook for Facebook language/framework and flux-machine-learning for Flux machine learning framework of Julia.